# how to change underline color on active link - react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have some logic for styling the active link in React and I have CSS for an animated underline on nav links. The problem is that I don't know how to change the color of the underline when the link is active.

In CSS, I think the selector would be `.nav-link:after:active`

How can I change the color of the underline when the link is active?

```
const isActive = (history, path) => {
  if (history.location.pathname === path) {
    return { color: "#ff7315" };
  } else {
    return { color: "#232020" };
  }
};
```

styles.css

```
  .nav-item { 
    display: table-cell; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .nav-link {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-link:after {    
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #3a3535;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
  }

  .nav-link:hover:after { 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the one you've provided.

```css
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.nav-link.active {
  color: blue
}

.nav-link:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.nav-link:hover:after,
.nav-link.active:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Some Link 1</a>
</div>

<div class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Some Link 2</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if you're using react-router or not. But if you are you can do it using `NavLink` like

```
<NavLink
   className="link-item"
   activeStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}
   to="/"
>
  Link
</NavLink>
```

Hope this helps !